# Is there an Emacs paredit hook available so I can redefine C-j?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I like using `C-j` to `eval-last-sexp` but paredit-mode (which I otherwise like) overrides this to `paredit-newline`. Looking in the paredit-mode docs I don't see anything like a `paredit-mode-hook` defined where I can `add-hook` to call `local-set-key` or a similar function.

Anyone have a suggestion?

**Update**
After trying out the two answers below and not having much success, I think the problem may be related to the fact that paredit is getting loaded in a few different contexts? To wit, I am opening both Common Lisp, Clojure and Emacs Lisp files, all of which can use paredit. Sadly, the various forms of `eval-last-sexp` have slightly different names in each mode, so I can't define the key once for everything. Rather, I need to bind the key based on the major mode that I am in also. Hopefully that adds another useful data point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to use hooks, something like the following should work:

```
(eval-after-load "paredit"
  #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'eval-last-sexp))
```

Alternatively, if for some reason that doesn't work, or you simply prefer the use of hooks, you can add the above `define-key` invocation to the hooks of the major modes for which `paredit` is activated.

Answer (score 6):

Every mode defined by one of the `define-*-mode` macros automatically runs a corresponding `MODE-hook`.

I see that paredit-mode is a minor mode defined with `(define-minor-mode paredit-mode ...)`, and therefore it will run `paredit-mode-hook`.

You can type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `define-minor-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> and search for `run-hooks` to see where this behaviour is defined.

**Edit** (based on addition to question):

Do they all use `C-x C-e` as a default binding for the mode-specific eval-last-sexp function, by any chance? That would seem like a consistent thing for them to do, and if so then you could use the following approach:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-j") (key-binding (kbd "C-x C-e")))
```

Comment: +1. Never realized that Emacs automated this behavior even when the hook variable wasn't explicitly defined by the mode in question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paredit-mode-hook.  You don't see it until you add something to it.  Weird, but this is the way hooks behave.

However, in your case, the best approach may be to clear the paredit binding for C-j:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
   #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") nil))
```

And then set your own via local-set-key in every major-mode hook.